# value object properties should be configured default value?

Tags: java, design-patterns, nullpointerexception, null

i use value object as the json which return to android client
such that

```
public class StationVO implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1692896969987787366L;

    private String stationName;

    private Long stationID;

    private Double stationLng;

    private Double stationLat;  
}
```

but my partner let me change as

```
public class StationVO implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1692896969987787366L;

    private String stationName="";

    private long stationID;

    private double stationLng;

    private double stationLat;
    }
```

because he think if you use object,the json my be have null,it can cause client application error,even
down,but i think if i use double the nullexception may be hidden,but i cant find the error.
besides if i use double,the original null change 0,could cause the unreal data.
so how can i avoid return null and i can find the nullexceptin or others to locate the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is almost unintelligible, so I will restrict myself to some advice:

Don't declare "scalar" fields with wrapper types *unless* your application requires the distinct meaning provided by `null`.  It is simpler and more efficient to use the primitive type for your scalars ... and you won't run into problems with NPEs.

In your example, you should only use `Double` for the longitude and latitude if you need to support stations with "unknown" or "unspecified" long/lat coordinates.  If you simply want to have a default value, then initialize the fields to the (numeric) default value; e.g. `0.0, 0,0`.

If you do need it to be possible for the long / lat fields to be `null`, then your code has to cope with this.

For detailed examples on debugging NPEs, read my Answer to this question:

- [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)